# Cell Complex: Proposition 5.5 in John Lee's book "Introduction to Topological Manifolds"

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

The proposition reads:
"Suppose $X$ is an $n$-dimensional CW complex. Then every $n$-cell of $X$ is an open subset of $X$."

The proof first shows that the intersection of any $n$-cell of $X$ with the closure of any other cell is the empty set. From this it is concluded that the intersection of any $n$-cell with the closure of every cell is open. Then it follows from the (W)-condition that the $n$-cell is open.

So far I can follow. However, the empty set is also closed. Thus, in my opinion, the conclusion could also be that every $n$-cell of $X$ is a closed subset of $X$. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to Lee's book, but usually we have characteristic maps $\Phi_\alpha:D^k_α\to X$ from the unit ball $D^k$ (where $k$ depends on the dimension of the cell $α$) to the CW complex $X$. The cell $e_α$ is then defined as the image $Φ_α(\text{int}D_α^k)$ of the interior. Using the Hausdorffness of $X$, it follows that the closure $\overline {e_α}$ of a cell is the image $Φ_α(D_α^k)$. Saying that $A\cap\overline{e_α}$ is closed is then the same as $Φ_α^{-1}(A)$ being closed in $D^k$.
Anyway, since the $n$-cell $e_\beta$ is disjoint from $Φ_α(D^k_α)$ for every $α\ne\beta$ (here it is important that there are no cell of higher dimension), these intersections are indeed empty, so it suffices to consider $Φ_\beta^{-1}(e_\beta)$, but that is just $\text{int}(D^n_\beta)$ as no point in $\partial D^n$ is mapped to $e_α$. So every preimage is open, making $e_α$ open.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. With "these intersections", do you mean $e_\beta \cap \overline{e_\alpha}$?

Comment: The point I do not understand in John Lee's proof is how he can conclude from $e_\alpha\cap\overline{e_\beta} = \emptyset$ that this intersection is open. I understand that $\emptyset$ is always both open and closed. But if you take $\emptyset$ to be closed here, you arrive at the conclusion that $e_\alpha$ is closed instead of open.

Comment: @JohannesWandinger: The intersection is empty only if $\beta\ne\alpha$. It all boils down to the intersection $e_α\cap\overline{e_α}$, and that one is not closed.

Comment: I think I got the point: $e_\alpha \cap \overline e_\beta = \emptyset \quad \forall \beta \ne \alpha$ and $e_\alpha \cap \overline e_\alpha = e_\alpha$ is open in $\overline e_\alpha$ (is it?), $e_\alpha \cap \overline e_\beta$ is open for all $\beta$, hence $e_\alpha$ is open in $X$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a general result here (see [Topology and Groupoids](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html) p.121).

A useful construction, due to JHC Whitehead, is that of the *adjunction space* $B \cup_f X$ from a space $B$ and a map $f: A \to B$ from a closed subset $A$ of $X$. We now recognise this as a special kind of pushout

$$\begin{matrix} A & \xrightarrow{f} & B \\
\downarrow && \downarrow\\
X & \to & B \cup_f X \end{matrix}$$

These conditions imply that the map $X \backslash A \to B \cup_f X$ is an open map.